# Aggregate a characteristic of k nearest neighbors

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two point datasets: *x* and *y*.

For each point in *x*, I'd like to find the average of some characteristic of its *k* nearest neighbors in *y*.

Below is some dummy data.  For each x, I'm looking for the average "Land" for its 3 nearest y neighbors.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

x <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/p5b7-5n3h?method=export&format=GeoJSON") %>% 
  st_transform(2272) %>% 
  st_make_grid(., cellsize = 10000, square = FALSE) %>% 
  st_centroid()

y <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/rarb-5ahf?method=export&format=GeoJSON") %>% 
  st_transform(2272) %>%
  st_centroid() %>% 
  mutate(Land = as.numeric(as.character(aland10))) %>% 
  select(Land)
```

One thing I've tried is get.knnx() from the FNN package, which returns a matrix *x* rows long and *k* columns wide, where each value is the row number for the *k*-th closest object in *y*.  I am not sure how to proceed from there, however.

```r
library(sf)
library(FNN)

index <- get.knnx(st_coordinates(y), st_coordinates(x), 3)$nn.index

head(index)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   36   98  163
[2,]   98  163   36
[3,]   98   36  163
[4,]   36   98  163
[5,]   36   98   97
[6,]   98  163  144
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close! `apply` over rows (`1`) of the nearest neighbour index matrix, using each row in a function to subset the `Land` vector from `y` and compute the mean:

```
> apply(index, 1, function(i){mean(y$Land[i])})
 [1] 1144241.0 1852318.3  518192.3  861482.7  870405.3 1735791.3  524817.7
 [8] 1128206.0  458384.0  813126.3 1018941.0  935856.0  357886.3  783506.7
[15] 1321931.0 1691426.0  714128.7  502033.3  300172.0  235375.0 1246772.3
[22] 1691426.0  521444.3  657274.0 2353606.3  411458.3 1393687.0
```

If you want to add that as a column in `x` do `x$MeanYLand = apply(...etc..)`

You can check this by hand for the first couple:

```
> mean(y$Land[index[1,]])
[1] 1144241
> mean(y$Land[index[2,]])
[1] 1852318
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're after:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(nngeo)

x <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/p5b7-5n3h?method=export&format=GeoJSON") %>% 
  st_transform(2272) %>% 
  st_make_grid(., cellsize = 10000, square = FALSE) %>% 
  st_centroid()

y <- st_read("https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/rarb-5ahf?method=export&format=GeoJSON") %>% 
  st_transform(2272) %>%
  st_centroid() %>% 
  mutate(Land = as.numeric(as.character(aland10))) %>% 
  select(Land)

k <- 3
nn <- st_nn(x, y, k=k)

# Method 1:
# Returns a vector of the mean land values
meanLandValues <- sapply(nn, FUN=function(indices){
    mean(y$Land[indices])
})

# Method 2:
# This way will keep the spatial attribute

# Add an ID column so that we can perform a spatial join later
x <- st_sf(data.frame(ID=1:length(x), geom=x))

joined <- st_join(x, y, join=st_nn, k=3, progress=FALSE)
meanLandValuesSF <- aggregate(joined, by=list(joined$ID), FUN=mean)
```